# How to install LibreOffice in Ubuntu 12.10 4.03.deb?

Tags: installation

I can not install LibreOffice-4.03_deb in Ubuntu 12.10. Uninstalled applications LibreOffice Native OS Ubuntu 12.10. Use the versions of Portuguese-BR.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the libre office repository. In terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

Then your libreoffice will be updated. If you didn't have install it yet, just go to Software Center and install it.

Hope this helps you :)